# Is this decreasing in the Harmonic Mean?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, harmonic-functions

Consider the following expression, where $H(\mathbf{x})$ is the harmonic mean of a vector $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$.

$$\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)H(\mathbf{x})-\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^2\frac{H(\mathbf{x})^2}{x_1}$$

Is the expression decreasing in $H(\mathbf{x})$?

---

It seems so: let $N$ denote $\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)$ and $K$ denote the harmonic mean:

$$NK-N^2\frac{K^2}{x_1}$$

$$D_k[..]= N-2N^2\frac{K}{x_1}<0$$

$$\iff 2N^2\frac{K}{x_1}>N$$

$$\iff K>\frac{x_1}{2N}$$

$$\iff H(\mathbf{x})>\frac{x_1}{2\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)}$$

$$\iff \frac{2(n-1)}{\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}}>x_1$$

$$\iff 2(n-1)>\frac{x_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

Which is true. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: P.s. if you answer it, I create a bounty in 2 days and reward it to you :)

Comment: What do you mean by decreasing? The expression is $n$ variables function, so what "decreasing" means?

Comment: @Holo as the harmonic mean increases, the expression decreases.

Comment: You still have $2$ variables $H$ and $x_1$

Comment: @Holo $H(\mathbf{x})$ is the harmonic mean, which is a function of $x_1$, but if you fix $x_1$, the expression seems decreasing in the harmonic mean.

Comment: **If** you **fix** $x_1$ you can look at $H$ as a variable and solve it like you did, yes